# Google Plus Share popup window image issue

Tags: google-plus

I use google+ share as link to an image (like https://plus.google.com/share?url=siteurl)

But lately it doesn't work smoothly. The image size appears bad on pop-up share window.

Could you please help me, how can I solve this one?

Example url : http://www.ikonmenkul.com.tr/ikonx-platform/?itemID=552505

Comment: What do you mean "image size appears bad"? Give an example of what you expect it to be like and what it's actually like.

Comment: @abraham thanks for your interest. You can see if you click Google plus button that fixed to right of site.

For example : https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ikonmenkul.com.tr%2F%2Fikonx-platform%2F

Answer (score 0):

All of the correct image sizes and specifications for enabling good-looking shares is documented in the recently published guide: [Article Rendering for Google+](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/article-rendering).